# Does "cout<<(char*)NULL" doing "close(1)" here?

Tags: c++, unix

In the following code I have used `cout<<(char*)NULL;` after this line, my program printing nothing to the output screen. Does it mean I have done `close(1)` with `cout` here? What is actually happening here? Is this a bug? Please share your thoughts.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(){
    cout<<"\nfun\n";
}

main(){
cout<<(char*)NULL;
f(); //not getting printed !
cout<<"\nhello\n";  //not getting printed !
cout<<"hii how are you?"; //not getting printed, why??
}
```

I have tried this with both gcc and DevCpp compilers, same behavior observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you sets the `badbit` on the stream which causes nothing to be printed after `cout<<(char*)NULL;`

```
if (!__s)
 __out.setstate(ios_base::badbit);
```

The standard says: `requires: shall not be a null pointer`. So your program definitely has the undefined behavior and it should be fixed. You can clear the bad bit by using `cout.clear()`.

In your case, `cout<<(char*)NULL;` causes undefined behavior. But GCC plays it safely.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

`cout << (char *)NULL` causes undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. (The compiler assumes you don't do this when it generates assembly code).

A `char *` argument used here must point to a character in a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 2):

`(char*)NULL` doesn't turn `NULL` into a string like `"NULL"` if that's what you thought. `NULL` is actually a macro which expands to `0`. Casting it to `char*` turns it into a pointer to zero (a null pointer). The only problem comes with printing it out. It is [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to try to print a null-pointer. Up to this point you cannot make sense of any behavior your program exhibits. The fact that your program didn't crash is a surprise to me.

Comment: Yes, It was surprising and I ran this sample program on my Linux (using both compiler gcc and clang) and it did not crash.