# Is printing a null-pointer Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, iostream, undefined-behavior, null-pointer

When studying the sample code for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283188) I had assumed it was Undefined Behaviour which was preventing subsequent uses of `std::cout` from printing. But it turns out that [attempting to print a null pointer caused `std::ios_base::badbit` and `std::ios_base::failbit` to be set in its stream state](http://ideone.com/B06vm0) which was the real cause for its being non-operational. Because of this, I am now curious if it really *is* Undefined Behaviour to (attempt) to print a null-pointer. So here   are my questions:

1. Is it Undefined Behaviour to print a null-pointer? If so, what is it about the stream inserter that would cause this? I'm pretty certain the inserter is smart enough to not dereference a null-pointer.
2. I would also like to know why the inserter sets its error mask when encountering a null-pointer in this context (specifically `badbit`). Why doesn't it treat it like the termination of a string literal?

I don't have a Standard handy, and I only found one source thus far that unfortunately led to a dead link.

Comment: libstdc++ might be doing an extra `nullptr` check when it's not required to. The program [seg faults](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2078b21d2ce9050d) when you build it with clang+libc++. but not with clang+libstdc++

Comment: "I'm pretty certain the inserter is smart enough to not dereference a null-pointer." - generally, the C++ standard says what compilers must do, and anything else, they don't have to do. It would slow down correctly-coded programs to do an extra NULL check before every call to `operator<<(char *)`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: lol I don't think the speed of a null check is a concern when working with something as horribly slow as C++ I/O streams.

Comment: **Closely related:** http://stackoverflow.com/q/7019454/560648 (almost a dupe, tbh)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`basic_ostream`'s `operator<<(basic_ostream<>&, const char*)` function requires that the `char*` is non-null - it is designed to print the string the pointer points to. So it is undefined behavior to send a null `char*` to `cout`. (See C++11 27.7.3.6.4/3 "Character inserter function templates").

However, `basic_ostream`'s `operator<<(basic_ostream<>&, const void*)` function simply prints the value of the pointer, so a null pointer will work properly with that overload.

Comment: If you quote the standard via `[ostream.inserters.character]` instead of doing `27.7.3.6.4` then it has more chance of still being a valid reference in a different version that may have renumbered chapters or sections.

Answer (score 2):

gcc `ostream.tcc` line 319:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
  basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
  operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
  {
    if (!__s)
__out.setstate(ios_base::badbit);
```

gcc is simply performing a check that the standard does not guarantee, which is fine because it's undefined anyway.