# Ignored parameters in std::cout after NULL

Tags: c++, cout

If I write this code:

```
const char * b = NULL;
std::cout << "Hello!" << b;
```

I get this output:

`Hello!`

However, if I change the order to:

```
const char * b = NULL;
std::cout << b << "Hello!";
```

I get no output whatsoever, so I'm curious about it.

I can guess that probably the << operator for cout reads until a NULL, so everything after it is ignored, but wonder if someone could give me some more insight about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Is printing a null-pointer Undefined Behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283772/is-printing-a-null-pointer-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator has a precondition:

> *Requires:* `s` shall not be a null pointer.

By breaking this precondition, you cause undefined behaviour. Anything could happen.

(As mentioned in the comments, one popular implementation sets `failbit` and `badbit` in this case, which would explain the behaviour you see. But that's not something you can rely on.)

Comment: [And, in practice, GCC (rather, libstdc++) sets badbit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7019483/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's interesting, and explains the observed behaviour. But it definitely can't be relied on.

Comment: [It also sets `badbit` on GCC](http://ideone.com/B06vm0)

Comment: @0x499602D2: You're absolutely right; I typo'd badbit for failbit in the above comment. :P Anyway, my answer that I linked to gives all the details.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Nope of course not :)